# Create VanillaForum topic from new piece of Craft content?

Tags: craft-features

Craft is looking perfect for a new project I'm starting, but I can't find a good way to integrate a key part of the site. I'll be creating content pages for each individual project that I'm featuring on my website. Ideally, Vanilla would be embedded below the page content and showing the relevant discussion thread.

It seems so simple but I'm having a tough time finding a good solution. Can anyone point me in a direction?